# Where it is generated SignInManager IdentityUser .cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Now I have spent almost a week in the IdentityUser Class
The reason I am a new asp.net core or I did not encounter a similar likeness,
When applying the lesson on the link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-enable-qrcodes?view=aspnetcore-2.1
File not found: EnableAuthenticator.cshtml
(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity) is the one who generates a view file, but the question here is if you can find this file in any way Note that the application created by newProject> asp.netCore MVC with authentication.
C:\WebApplicationCore\WebApplicationCore\Views\Shared_LoginPartial.cshtml

```
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <form asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Logout</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

Note that the desired page appears in the browser on
https: // localhost: **** / Identity / Account / Manage / EnableAuthenticator
This file does not exist at all in the project folders, is it possible to find and edit it.

> I apologize if you have difficulty in containing the problem because I
>   use Google translation

Comment: Its been moved into its own Razor Pages library. [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/master/src/UI)

Comment: Can I edit the page and add code to it?

Comment: @Sultan You can [Scaffold Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity) and then edit pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we create an ASP.NET Core MVC application with Individual Authentication, the account management views and/or pages are hidden.

Where are they? They are compiled views/pages in the ASP.NET Core Identity package; we can see them in the GitHub repository. For instance, here is the [EnableAuthenticator page](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/c7276ce2f76312ddd7fccad6e399da96b9f6fae1/src/UI/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/EnableAuthenticator.cshtml).

To surface those pages in our project, we need [to scaffold Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity). Here is how to do it from the dotnet command line interface.

This assumes ASP.NET Core 2.1.0 (check via `dotnet --info`).

```
// create a new app
dotnet new mvc --auth Identity

// install the code generator tool
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --version 2.1.0

// add the code generation package
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design --version 2.1.0
dotnet restore

// generate the enable authenticator file
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --files Account.Manage.EnableAuthenticator
```

There are a lot of other files we can generate.

```
// view the help
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -h

// list the available files to generate
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --listFiles
```

Comment: I really appreciate this effort and it is a highlight to me and in addition to my abilities, thank you very much for this explanation.
Very beautiful possibility of scaffold to fetch the hidden as possible that can reverse the process and hide the apparent or the process is just generating a code written in advance.